# KQL | summarize arg_max

Tags: azure, logging, kql

I am trying to develop a kql quers as follows

```
ConfigurationData
| where Computer contains "XXXX"
| where ConfigDataType contains "WindowsServices"
| where SvcDisplayName contains "World Wide Web Publishing Service" 
| order by TimeGenerated desc
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, SvcDisplayName, SvcState
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SvcState
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, SvcDisplayName, SvcState
```

with this script I am trying to filter the services that are stopped in our Virtual machines. the problem is the service is stopped first and in millisecond will be running but the both stopped and running will be saved in the log analytics workspace at the same time.

[image]

when I will call the last record with this line

```
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated,SvcState, *) by Computer, SvcDisplayName
```

it brings me the stopped status which is wrong (The service is running). can you suggest me a kql command that after filtering the SvcState take always the running and not stopped.  or fix the query somehow that if the data is saved in exactly the same time take the status of running.

Answer (score 0):

When the latest record has both `running` and `stopped` status, `arg_max()` function can take any of the rows. In this case, in order to take the latest row with `running` state, you can create a flag as **1** when **SvcState** is `Running` and **0** when it is `stopped`.  Then concat the value of Timestamp and flag that is created from **SvcState** field and take row with maximum concatenated value in each Computer, SvcDisplayName  group. Below is the code

```
........
| extend flag=iif(SvcState=="Running",1,0)
| summarize arg_max(strcat(TimeGenerated,flag), *) by Computer, SvcDisplayName
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, SvcDisplayName, SvcState
```

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA9VSy2rDMBC8%2BysWn%2ByigpNjik8N9FZKHUihlCJbG2eLLRlJzqP047suiWMnhB56qhAIZndnB81U6OHe6BWVrZWejJ5LLyEFxY%2BXeYXRgmp8QI1cRjVjHD0jgqfqpvVoZ85b0qU40HTzi32DPZxtijm5ppL7R1mP4IxXHIE4eA2Az5E%2FmibTyW3SXUiSWXcnsYDwhU%2FI75K0MluXod1Qge4HMrZSsCSFsMQcntq8Irdmbjh0dU2ZN02DKhQX26b%2FfttzqzVDYfB2F1x4GnzBdo0We9%2BgMNpL0u6weNAw9HHQdq6rnxhbPJz4VTYwibGK5eR7GEUNFLqCq401H1j4cfEUv%2FOAnZLFs7jzqBWsKlmmRKvoWErT%2FrPERCQxt7q2rqWlTwRpy%2Fda7iIOZiH9OP%2Bio2KvbuJO7zUNf1H9DRaSKBeRAwAA)